# App will not compile for windows arm

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-rt

I am creating a new release for my app in order to fix some screen size settings (In my prior release I did not take into account different screen sizes and I hardcoded the positions of each thing in my xaml code) and I have issues with compiling for ARM. My prior release included the extended splash classes and coded in order to notify the user that the app is getting ready. But some things were scattered around the screen in larger screens and I made a new version of the app in order to fix this. Now when I try to create the app packages for the store the ARM package is not created. 
I am getting 5 errors:

```
Error   1   The name "LayoutAwarePage" does not exist in the namespace "using:Greek_Blogs.Common".  D:\Skydrive\Cyprus RSS Reader\RSSReader\WindowsBlogReader\ItemsPage.xaml    1   1   Greek Blogs Reader

Error   2   The member "Resources" is not recognized or is not accessible.  D:\Skydrive\Cyprus RSS Reader\RSSReader\WindowsBlogReader\ItemsPage.xaml    14  5   Greek Blogs Reader
Error   3   The name "AdControl" does not exist in the namespace "using:Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI".    D:\Skydrive\Cyprus RSS Reader\RSSReader\WindowsBlogReader\ItemsPage.xaml    146 13  Greek Blogs Reader

Error   4   The name "FeedDataSource" does not exist in the namespace "using:Greek_Blogs".  D:\Skydrive\Cyprus RSS Reader\RSSReader\WindowsBlogReader\App.xaml  1   1   Greek Blogs Reader

Error   5   The name "DateConverter" does not exist in the namespace "using:Greek_Blogs".   D:\Skydrive\Cyprus RSS Reader\RSSReader\WindowsBlogReader\App.xaml  1   1   Greek Blogs Reader
```

My questions are:
Why are these errors appearing only in ARM compilation?
Why they appear now and not before since they belong in xaml pages I did not edit?
How can I fix them?

Also if a create a package for AnyCPU will it work on ARM? by definition AnyCPU contains ARM but since I do not own an ARM device I cannot test it so I am asking here

Comment: Do you use any third-party controls? Try to clean the solution before build.

Comment: I did clean it. At first I was trying to implement AdRotator, but I removed everything since I it was not ready yet and my app needed a new release version to fix bugs, I cleaned the solution aswel but still nothing. I created an anyCPU appx package and uploaded it to the store but still wondering what was what with the errors

Comment: AdControl is still here as log says. Try to inspect your sources more, I think that you still have some pieces of code related to this control and as result you get this strange error.

Comment: Adcontrol is Microsofts Ad system (pubcenter) which worked in the previous release of my app